# PHP: Play sound file from server on client site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Want to play a file that on path like this `/var/spool/sound/dog.wav` present on server.
This not having any
**1)`URL`**
**2) Not even on present in that `website root folder`**
How i can make my client to listen to that dog.wav ?

I am getting file path by using `Tree view` client click on a file, it returns the path of that file being clicked. If you can tell me any tree view that having function to play sound file that it would be a great contribution from you.
Thanks a lot
GOD BLESS YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean there's an audio file outside of your website root folder. Am I right?

In that case you can use Apache virtual directory (if you are using Apache) and make your path visible from an url, for example `http://address/sound/` an then use any kind of audio players that you want to play your file (now you can access your audio file via `http://address/sound/dog.wav`). user1352571 is showing you HTML5 solution.

Comment: Thats mean I have to do Alias setting in my Apache server. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It's like DocumentRoot /var/spool/sound
<Directory /sound>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Comment: You can find complete documentation for this here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to play audio files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir its only working on a file that present in that website folder. I need to play a file that is present on other hard-drive partition. I think some PHP code would be required and thanks for this audio tag.